# Ruby NameError: Undefined local variable

Tags: ruby

Just started to go through the 7 languages in 7 weeks book; day one problem make a simple higher or lower game in ruby. When I execute my script I get the following error but I don't know why.

EDIT: This is thrown after I guess once.

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `actual' for main:Object
>           from guess_game.rb:2:in`guess'
>           from guess_game.rb:22

```
def guess(guess, acutal)
  unless guess == actual
    if guess > actual
      puts 'Lower'
    else
      puts 'Higher'
    return false
    end
  end
  puts 'Correct'
  return true
end



answer = rand(10)
game_won = false
puts 'I am thinking of a number, what is it?'
until game_won
  num = gets.to_i
  # Static Debug Line
  puts "Guess #{num} : Answer #{answer}"
  game_won = guess(num, answer)
end
```

Comment: You misspelled actual as "acutal" in your function parameters.

Comment: misstyped `acutal` in the method signature

Comment: ... school boy error thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def guess(guess, actual)
  unless guess == actual
    if guess > actual
      puts 'Lower'
    else
      puts 'Higher'
    return false
    end
  end
  puts 'Correct'
  return true
end
```

Problem: Spelling mistake, Corrected